# Is there any package management system for MinGW+MSYS?

Tags: gcc, mingw, apt-get, package-managers, msys

I am trying to compile some open source libraries in `MinGW`+`MSYS`. During the `configure` phase, I kept seeing some 3rd party libraries are missing.

For now, my solution is to download the source of the missing libraries and follow the GNU build process to compile and install them into my MinGW environment.

Is there any package management system for `MinGW`+`MSYS` to install packages easily? Just like `apt-get`.

I tried the `mingw-get` for the missing package. But it reports the error below.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mingw-get` *is* the (closest equivalent to apt-get) package manager for MinGW and MSYS. However, it can only manage packages which are actually *available* for MinGW and/or MSYS, (either because a MinGW developer has built and packaged them, or a member of the MinGW user community has contributed them).

Arbitrarily guessing what packages may be available, and even what their correct package names may be, is unlikely to be productive. Run mingw-get in its GUI mode, (if it's properly installed, just running `mingw-get` without arguments should start it in this mode), to see a list of packages which are actually available; if you don't see any likely candidates for what you are looking for, then it doesn't (yet) exist. In that case, you will need to either find a non-MinGW alternative build, or build it yourself, from source. (If you choose the latter option, and your build is successful, then you may wish to consider contributing it to MinGW.org).

Comment: Obviously, the switch to MSYS2 is your choice to make; consequently, I can be of no further assistance to you.

Comment: ditto on MSYS2... thanks for the info here. This is really only an issue for OS<Win10

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://web.archive.org/web/20210327023812/https://www.mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds) works for me as a "package manager".

Comment: Gives an error `404 - Not found`. [An Archive version of the site](http://web.archive.org/web/20210327023812/https://www.mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds) was added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install MSYS2. It comes with a package manager called `pacman`.

Comment: When you installed either MSYS2 or MinGW on your Windows™ computer, there should have been a startup icon for the terminal or console application.  `pacman` is a default, integral component of MSYS2 or MinGW and should be runnable from this console window.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I did install `MinGW` on Windows, but `Username@PCName MINGW64 ~ $ pacman --version` gives me `bash: pacman: command not found`.

Comment: @Cadoiz, see https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman/issues/50 for binary installation instructions.