# Impossible to build the Gambit Python extension on Windows

Tags: python, game-theory

I am trying to install the Gambit Python extension in order to study game theory but I encounter several issues.

I understand that I have to build Gambit first and then build the Python extension. Therefore, as stated (https://github.com/gambitproject/gambit/blob/master/doc/build.rst) I installed MinGW, then in MinGW I installed the autoconf, automake and libtool packages.
I then proceeded with their instructions and cloned Gambit from github, then cd gambit.

However, aclocal would not work after this :

```
Le programme «aclocal» n’a pas pu s’exécuter: Aucune application n’est associée au fichier spécifié pour cette
opérationAu caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ aclocal
+ ~~~~~~~.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ aclocal
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: "aclocal would not work after this" is not specific enough (as in, _at all_). Please elaborate: did you get an error? What's the error message? Did everything crash? What command produced that behaviour?

Comment: I have edited my initial message to include the error message.

Comment: This is actually great that you did that, I was just writing a comment about how important it is to include errors in one's post and format them. Looks like you don't have `aclocal` installed. MinGW should have a package manager (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046903/is-there-any-package-management-system-for-mingwmsys/30048170)), use it to install `aclocal`, `automake` and friends

Comment: There are files named aclocal, automake, autoconf and libtools in C:\MinGW\bin. I added C:\MinGW\bin in the path (however the aclocal file for example is not a .exe). I tried mingw-get install aclocal but it is an unknown package.