# cross-compile C-Lang with cURL

Tags: c, curl, cross-compiling

So, i have a script which does a get request to `https://guthib.com/` and prints the response.
I Use cURL lib for that...

Let's Say It's In The File <kbd>test.c</kbd>
Here's The Code For <kbd>test.c</kbd>

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode response;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://guthib.com/");

        response = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (response != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Request failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(response));
        } else {
            printf("%u", response);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

I am Compiling It For Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `i686-w64-mingw64-gcc` respictively.
But when I do, it says

```c
test.c:2:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The Command I Used For Compile Is -

```py
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.c -lcurl
```

Comment: Did you check the i686-w64-mingw32 development include files/libraries you need are installed on your development machine ? in the case there would be present, but in some non-standard location, you would need to use a command such as: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I<path-to-curl-include-dir> -L<path-to-curl-lib-dir> -o test.exe test.c -lcurl`.

Comment: I searched a lot but couldn't find the `include files/libs` docs.
Can You Please Provide Me The Docs Link?

Comment: See the answer to [Is there any package management system for MinGW+MSYS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046903/is-there-any-package-management-system-for-mingwmsys)